# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/edit"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am new to Ruby on Rails and tried finding the answers to my question on here but I haven't found anything to help me. I tried adding a patch to my routes file but I don't think I am doing it correctly.

**routes.rb**

```
 get 'website_sign_up' => 'users#new'
 post '/users' => 'users#create'
 get "users/:id/edit" => "users#edit", :as => :user
 patch "users/update" => "users#update", :as => "users/update"
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
 @user = User.new
end


def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/signup_success'
   else
    render 'new'
   end

end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
       flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
       redirect_to @user

    else
       render 'edit'
    end
end

private

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone)
   end
end
```

If someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: what is not working and what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I am trying to update the user profile. I can create one, just can't update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect to see an `:id` param in your patch/put route. Perhaps that is the problem. If you are using a form helper for the form, I suspect that is it.

Anyways, I would **strongly strongly strongly** recommend you follow Rails conventions and use the `resources` directive to specify your RESTful routes.

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :users
```

Add this line to your routes file and run `rake routes` from the command line to see the routes this generates for you.

You can read more about RESTful resource routing in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). By default, the directive will create the following routes:

```
GET         /users            users#index
GET         /users/new        users#new
POST        /users            users#create
GET         /users/:id        users#show
GET         /users/:id/edit   users#edit
PATCH/PUT   /users/:id        users#update
DELETE      /users/:id        users#destroy
```

**I would use this as your starting point.**

You can restrict which routes it generates if you want:

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I will start from scratch with your suggestion and see how it works, thanks!

Comment: I removed what I had and added resources :users and it worked, thanks!.

Comment: Great. Happy to help!